# Graph theory problem about vertices

Tags: graph-theory

If G is a connected graph with 100 vertices, and each vertex has at least degree 10, then prove that there is a path with at least 21 vertices in G

How can I solve this problem? I know it has something to do with the fact that 21 is around 10 times 2

Comment: Review the proof of Dirac's theorem you saw in class.

Comment: ok i looked at dirac, and now i'm thinking -

Comment: if i have 20 vtxs with each at least degree ten, i have a hamiltonian path, 
and all i have to do is extend the path by 1, since i have 80 remaining 
vertices, so now I have a path of 21 and the rest of the vertices I can
just add whatever, hence >= 21, is that a good enough proof?

Comment: If you don't convice yourself then is not.

Comment: Cool question bro! Here is what I found so far: Assuming the graph is triangle-free then it has a path of length at least 19. You consider the longest path v1v2....vl, and v1 has all its neighbours in the path. From this, we get that the path is of length at least 10. But no triangles means no consecutive neighbours of vl on the path, so need to add at least 9 no neighbours of vl on the path to give a path of length 19? DOES this help?

Comment: @Misha , the proof of Dirac's theorem in my notes uses induction on the number of absent edges of the graph for it to be complete. And the induction steps make use of machinery that divides the vertices of the Hamiltonian cycle, in the graph resulted from the old one by adding a new edge, into two groups that have a non-trivial intersection. And from that generate another Hamiltonian path. I don't see how that can be used in this problem? Please help!

Comment: That's disappointing - there is a proof of Dirac's theorem that immediately implies this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm to construct such a path.

First, start with a single edge and greedily extend it in both directions. That is, for as long as you can add another edge to either end of the path which doesn't visit a previously used vertex, do so.

When we're done, we have a path on vertices $v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$, visiting them in exactly this order, such that all neighbors of $v_0$ and $v_k$ are also on the path (or else we could extend it). We may assume that $k < 20$, because if $k\ge 20$, we are done.

Let $S \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ be the set of indices $i$ such that $v_0$ is adjacent to $v_i$, and let $T \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ be the set of indices $i$ such that $v_{i-1}$ is adjacent to $v_k$. Because the graph has minimum degree $10$, and all neighbors of $v_0$ and $v_k$ are on the path, we have $|S|\ge 10$ and $|T|\ge 10$.

But $S$ and $T$ together are contained in a set of size less than $20$. So there is no room for them to be disjoint: there must be an index $i \in S\cap T$, meaning that $v_0$ is adjacent to $v_i$ **and** $v_{i-1}$ is adjacent to $v_k$. This turns our path into a cycle: $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_{i-1}, v_k, v_{k-1}, \dots, v_i, v_0$.

Since the graph is connected and has more than $k+1$ vertices, at least one vertex on this cycle must have a neighbor $w$ outside $\{v_0, v_1, \dots, v_k\}$. This lets us make a longer path: start at $w$, take the edge to the cycle, and then walk all the way around the cycle.

Now go back to the first step, extending this path greedily, and repeat. This algorithm lets us keep going for as long as the path has fewer than $21$ vertices, so it stops when it finds a path on $21$ vertices or more.

This algorithm generalizes in two ways:

- If the graph has minimum degree $d$, is connected, and has at least $2d+1$ vertices, then it contains a path on $2d+1$ vertices by this argument.
- If the graph has minimum degree $d$ and has $n \le 2d$ vertices (in which case it's automatically connected), then the only place this algorithm can stop is when we're looking for the vertex $w$ and can't find it because there are no other vertices in the graph. In this case, we've found a Hamiltonian cycle. This is a proof of Dirac's theorem.